# Iteration vector 5 in 5 seconds c

Tags: c++

How can I iterate a vector  5 in 5 seconds?

Example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    cout << vector[count] << endl;
    //sleep 5 seconds
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Are you just asking how to sleep for 5 seconds? `<thread>`+`<chrono>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the vector has 5 elements:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread> /* introduced with c++11,
                     make sure your compiler is up to date
                     and is set to compile c++ with this version
                     of the STL and standard
                  */
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    cout << vector[count] << endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
```

You can also use `Sleep(n)` from `<windows.h>` alternatively.

Comment: There is no other way? The code is to be used in various environments, so not everyone can have this version of c++.

Comment: @PhilipJar I'm not familiar with anything else. Sorry :(

Comment: Boost: `boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(1000))`

Comment: @philipJar Well from C.O's comment Boost has good utilities for this.